# Apache2 as proxy to spring boot application ommiting slashes on login/logout

Tags: apache, spring-boot, spring-security, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am developing a spring boot application which is being deployed on apache2 as a proxy with https. Locally everything works correctly but when I deploy the application to the server whenever I want to access the site that requires authentication I should be redirected to the login page, instead, apache2 just appends "login" to the domain name and displays error as there is no such mapping. The same situation occurs with logout. After invoking /logout there is a redirection to login?logout or login?error, both of this form works correctly as I can access them If I fix link by myself but apache2 just appends "login?logout" to domain name instead of adding slash before. Here is my virtual hosts configuration:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>      
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.key        
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```